# how to erase min element from one vector and add to another, while first becames empty?

Tags: c++, c++11

how to erase min element from one vector and add to another while first becames empty?`
thats not working:/
it looks like selectsort algorithm

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
void print(vector<int>&vec) {
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
        cout << vec[i] << endl;
}


int main()
{
    vector<int>v1{ 458,525,255,336,258 };
    int size = v1.size() - 1;
    vector<int>v2;
    int min = v1[0];
    int i;
    int ind = 0;
    while (v2.size() != size) {
        for (i = 1; i < v1.size(); i++)
        {
            if (v1[i] < min)
            {
                min = v1[i];
                ind = i;
            }
        }
        v2.push_back(min);
        v1.erase(v1.begin() + ind);
    }
    print(v1);
    cout << " " << endl;
    print(v2);

}
```

Comment: *"thats not working"* is not a helpful explanation of your problem. Please explain the nature of the error. Does it compile? Does it run? What result were you expecting? What result did you get, and how does it compare with what you expected? Please take a moment to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux `size` is equal to `v1.size() - 1`  why it never be false? (why it is -1 is another question)

Comment: @Slava That was `v2.size() != v1.size()` in my mind, my mistake!

Comment: cant figure out, that adds min element five time, probably erase doesnot work

Comment: I would guess the problem is you don't reset `min` and `ind` after the first iteration. It still has the first minimum value, which is by definition no greater than any other value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how it should be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {

    std::vector<int> v1{ 458, 525, 255, 336, 258 };
    std::vector<int> v2;

    while ( v1.size() ) {

        auto m = std::min_element(v1.begin(), v1.end());
        v2.push_back(*m);
        v1.erase(m);

    }

    for (auto v : v1) std::cout << v << " "; std::cout << "\n";
    for (auto v : v2) std::cout << v << " "; std::cout << "\n";

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: An answer consisting only of code is incomplete. Please explain how your solution answers the question or the purpose of the changes you've made to the original code.

Comment: `while ( v1.size() )` can also be written as `while ( !v1.empty() )` instead

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear why target size for `v2` is `v1.size() - 1`, after you sort all elements `v1.size()` should be 0 and `v2.size()` is equal to size of `v1` before sorting. Issue with improper sorting - you initialize `ind` and `min` wrong place. It should be inside the first loop (and note you do not need to keep `min` value, index is enough):

```
while (v1.size()) {
    size_t ind = 0;
    for (size_t i = 1; i < v1.size(); i++)
    {
        if (v1[i] < v1[ind])
        {
            ind = i;
        }
    }
    v2.push_back(v1[ind]);
    v1.erase(v1.begin() + ind);
}
```

But you better use standard algorithm [`std::min_element()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element):

```
while( not v1.empty() ) {
    auto it = std::min_element( v1.begin(), v1.end() );
    v2.push_back( *it );
    v1.erase( it );
}
```